# CSS @media queries only work in Device Mode of Developer Tools - React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So as the title describes, I've developed a responsive web app using **React** framework with several **@media queries**;
When I resize the page with the **Device Mode** of Developer Tools, queries work absolutely fine and everything behave as they should, but when I resize the actual browser window, media queries don't work. I even tried changing screen resolution and the issue still was there.

**These are my @media queries :**

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 768px) {...}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 768px) and (min-device-width: 691px) {...}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 768px) and (min-device-width: 576px) {...}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 939px) and (min-device-width: 769px) {...}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 940px) {...}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1024px) {...}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1200px) {...}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1510px) {...}
```

It may seem a little bit messy but because of some situations I had to mix the min and max criteria, and it works on Device Mode totally fine.

**And the HTML viewport meta tag:**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

I also tried changing or removing viewport meta tag but still no chance.

What could be the problem ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`device-width` has been deprecated and is likely the reason why you're not seeing the change on your desktop device since current browsers don't support it. Change your queries to just `max` or `min` `-width`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/device-width

Here's an example. You'll see that the first @media with device width never actually kicks on (the light blue) but the red one does
https://jsfiddle.net/astombaugh/bceg3nts/5/

```css
body {
  background-color: yellow;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  body {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
</head>
<body>

<h1>The @media Rule</h1>

<p>Resize the browser window. When the width of this document is 600 pixels or less, the background-color is "lightblue", otherwise it is "yellow".</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So the problem was using of deprecated device-width! Is there any hub that keeps us updated about things getting deprecated ? or we need to check everything from time to time ?

Comment: @yavarSt There are quite a few websites (including the one we're on!) with articles on changes but the web moves fast so you have to be mindful of the date of whatever articles or comments you're reading. Tutorials or guides that show you how to do something that were made 5 years ago might use features that are no longer supported and thus outdated. https://caniuse.com/ where they discuss new features and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ has references, guides, and examples for just about everything. It's tough, but if you get stuck we're all here to help each other :)

Comment: Thank you, sure we are :)